# Sending username and password as cleartext to web API from iOS

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, ssl

I am wondering if someone can validate or share their thoughts on the below.

I am creating an iOS app that uses a lot of API calls (REST). Users of the app are required to authenticate with an email and password they setup during registration. When they register or login, I generate an auth token on the server for the user to use for that session. Each subsequent API call I am sending the users password and auth token to validate and if successful proceed with their request. I store the auth token and password in keychain and use their email as the key.

At the moment the passwords are stored hashed/salted in MySQL but when I send from the app to the API the password is sent in cleartext. The connection is over SSL so is sending in cleartext OK or should I preform the same hashing in the app and send that value? I realise sending a hash could be a bad thing as a user would then get the hashed value.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You might want to take look at- http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64631/is-it-safe-to-send-clear-usernames-passwords-on-a-https-connection-to-authentica

Comment: This is great. Thanks for sharing the link.